# SAS MDX check if time member belongs to 3 last periods

Tags: date, range, sas, mdx, belongs-to

In MDX I need to define a measure that is calculated for all months except last N months.
For measure that becomes NULL in last 2 months I did this:

```
DEFINE Member '[Cube].[Measures].[my measure]' AS 
'iif([DateDimension].[DateHierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER is 
[DateDimension].[DateHierarchy].[All Months from hierarchy].LastChild.LastChild.Lag(1)
OR [DateDimension].[DateHierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER is 
[DateDimension].[DateHierarchy].[All Months from hierarchy].LastChild.LastChild,
NULL,[Measures].[Measure XXX])';
```

And this works fine, but now I need to create lots of measures that should be NULLed in last 2, 4, 6 and 12 months. Above solution would work but would be very messy, so **my question is:
Is there an MDX function / operator that allows to do somenting like this**:

```
[DateDimension].[DateHierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER between STH
```

OR

```
[DateDimension].[DateHierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER >= 
[DateDimension].[DateHierarchy].lastChild.lastChild.lag(N)
```

?

I checked the GT (greater or equal ) operator but this works only for comparing measures